# Truth in Advaita

Tags: philosophy, advaita, adi-shankaracharya, maya

To which theory of truth does the advaita vedanta relate? The correspondance theory, the coherence theory, or another one?
If truth, in Adi Shankara's comprehension, is understood as the correspondence between a proposition and a fact/state of things, does it mean that all truth is always relative, since the proposition and the state of things to which it points are "both" illusions, only valid at the phenomenal level, because ultimately there is only Brahman? If truth is relative, how can relativism be avoided? Does this mean that in the advaita védanta, Brahman transcends the true and the false? Is it to be understood that he transcends being and non-being, and that the positive standard of being and truth are in his manifested face: Ishvara?
I've heard that Indian thinkers had already formalized the Gettier problem?
Thank you.

Comment: You have multiple questions in one questions. Narrow your focus and ask them as separate questions.